# Getting error in mongodb connection during test case?

Tags: django, mongodb

I am getting the following error during test condition. I did not understand where i am doing mistake.

```
    client = MongoClient(settings.MONGO_HOST, settings.MONGO_PORT)

    raise TypeError("port must be an instance of int")
    TypeError: port must be an instance of int
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `settings.MONGO_PORT` value is most likely a string, while it should be an integer.

You can either change it at the source, or cast it here at the call site:

```
client = MongoClient(settings.MONGO_HOST, int(settings.MONGO_PORT))
```